# change the placeholder date from bootstrap input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am styling a form with bootstrap. 
I have an input field where I want the user to insert a date. The HTML is coded this way:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="entry_date">Date of entry:</label>
    <input type="date" name='entry_date' class="form-control" id="entry_date"
    <span class="help-block">Some helpful words here</span>
</div>
```

Bootstrap populates this field automatically with a placeholder which says `dd/mm/yyyy`.
How can I overwrite this? I need it so I can repopulate the field (eg. when reloading the form after a partial submission)

Comment: As far as I know its not possible to specify a placeholder other than dd/mm/yyyy for input fields type="date".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a bootstrap problem, it's the new HTML5 date-input control

Just use the value attribute as below:

```
 <input type="date" name='entry_date' class="form-control" id="entry_date" value="2012-12-12">
```

Other attributes are documented on [the W3C page here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

[A JSBIN showing the attribute in action here](http://jsbin.com/eNiRUvu/1/edit)

Comment: W3C page says document not found.